# Blender copies objects when I double click

Tags: interface, mouse

whenever I double click blender displays a message saying "Copied 1 selected object(s)" at the bottom bar.. I want to get rid of that as it is getting annoying.[image: As you can see it makes copies by just double clicking]

Help is appreciated, I am using 2.83 on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had an application called "Qtranslate" activated so it caused this problem. once I closed it the problem dissappeared